# Instantiate Flow using dict instead of file

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-oauth

I've searched quite hard for this. How do you make it accept a `dict` form of the `client_secret` instead of a file.

```py
flow = Flow.from_client_secrets_file(
    client_secrets_file="./client_secret.json",
    scopes=["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email", "openid"],
    redirect_uri="my redirect uri"
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I really went into the source code to find out since no one could help me.

You can use `Flow.from_client_config()`, wherethe first positional argument is a `Mapping[str,Any]` (i.e.`dict`) instead of the `client_secrets.json` file.